# SnowFlake's performance on group by vs partition on vs distinct

Tags: database, group-by, distinct, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, partition-by

I have a table in Snowflake. One of the columns in the table is called `obj_key`(object key).
The table size is very large (in TBs), so performance is desirable.

Now, a new entry is added to the table everytime an update on an object is done. The newly inserted row has the same `obj_key`, but a different entry in the `time_modified` column. Suppose I want to fetch distinct `obj_key` from the table, subject to certain conditions.

There are three approaches which I have:

Approach 1:

```
SELECT obj_key 
FROM my_table
WHERE some_condition
GROUP BY obj_key;
```

Approach 2:

```
SELECT distinct(obj_key) 
FROM my_table
WHERE some_condition;
```

Approach 3:

```
SELECT obj_key
FROM my_table
WHERE some_condition
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY obj_key ORDER BY obj_key) = 1;
```

So essentially my question boils down to these:

I had read that `distinct` on multiple columns is performed by `group_by(col1, col2, ..., col n)`. So how does the performance differ on the two (if it does)?

Since `PARTITION BY` also requires an `ORDER BY`, does it not drastically reduce the performance?

I'd love if someone could provide the nitty-gritties of how these queries run on SnowFlake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First two queries can be executed with same execution plan, based on cardinality expectation of Snowflake.

Your third approach will use a window function operator, and it would probably take more time.

As you have the dataset, I would **HIGHLY** recommend you to do your own tests, and observe the execution plans and the performance:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-query-profile.html#how-to-access-query-profile

Actually, I did some tests with SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA database, and I can see that first two queries are executed with same execution plan, and perform better than 3rd query.

Comment: Yes, I had been playing around with the query profile, and running different queries. However, I saw that the `group by` had similar run-time as that of `partition over`, which is why I asked this question. I also tried creating a `row number() over partition` as a new column `RN`, and then fetched only those rows with `RN=1`. This too, to my greatest surprise, had similar performance.

Comment: @ghost can you please tell me how big your test data set sample was.